# Using System.CommandLIne to parse options and commands with options

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, system.commandline

**Scenario**: I want to parse a console app's command line that has a number of options (that *don't* relate to a command), and a command that has a number of options. I've simplified what I'm trying to into a fictitious example. E.g. `myapp --i infile.dat --o outfile.dat conversion --threshold 42`

**Problem**: I'm finding that if I put the "conversion" command and it's option on the command-line then *only* its handler gets called, but *not* the handler for the root command. So I have no way to determine the values of the root command's --i and --o options.

(Conversely, if I omit the "conversion" command then root command's handler only is called - which is what i would expect.)

**Example code**:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Conversion command
        var thresholdOpt = new Option<int>("--threshold");
        var conversionCommand = new Command("conversion") { thresholdOpt };
        conversionCommand.SetHandler(
            (int threshold) => { Console.WriteLine($"threshold={threshold}"); },
            thresholdOpt);

        // Root command
        var infileOpt = new Option<string>("--i");
        var outfileOpt = new Option<string>("--o");
        var rootCommand = new RootCommand("test") { infileOpt, outfileOpt, conversionCommand };
        rootCommand.SetHandler(
            (string i, string o) => { Console.WriteLine($"i={i}, o={o}"); },
            infileOpt, outfileOpt);

        return await rootCommand.InvokeAsync(args);
    }
}
```

**Unexpected outputs**:

```
> myapp --i infile.dat --o outfile.dat conversion --threshold 42

threshold=42
```

In the above I expect to see the value for the --i and --o options, as well as the threshold options associated with the conversion command, but the root command's handler isn't invoked.

**Expected outputs**:

```
> myapp --i infile.dat --o outfile.dat 

i=infile.dat, o=outfile.dat

> myapp conversion --threshold 42

threshold=42
```

The above are what I'd expect to see.

**Dependencies**: I'm using System.CommandLine 2.0.0-beta3.22114.1, System.CommandLine.NamingConventionBinder v2.0.0-beta3.22114.1, .net 6.0, and Visual Studio 17.1.3.

I'd be grateful for help in understanding what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [docs sample](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/blob/main/docs/How-To.md#add-a-subcommand-or-verb) it seems only one verb gets executed. For example next:

```
var rootCommand = new RootCommand();
rootCommand.SetHandler(() => Console.WriteLine("root"));
var verbCommand = new Command("verb");
verbCommand.SetHandler(() => Console.WriteLine("verb"));
rootCommand.Add(verbCommand);
var childVerbCommand = new Command("childverb");
childVerbCommand.SetHandler(() => Console.WriteLine("childverb"));
verbCommand.Add(childVerbCommand);

return await rootCommand.InvokeAsync(args);
```

For no arguments will print `root`, for `verb` will print `verb` and for `verb childverb` will print `childverb`.

So if you need multiple actions performed it seems you will need to use another approach (for example manually processing `rootCommand.Parse()` result).

If you just want `"--i"` and `"--o"` accessible for `conversion` then add them to corresponding command:

```cs
// actually works without specifying infileOpt, outfileOpt on conversionCommand 
// but should be still present on the root one
// also rootCommand.AddGlobalOption can be a more valid approach
var conversionCommand = new Command("conversion") { thresholdOpt, infileOpt, outfileOpt}; 

// add here for handler
conversionCommand.SetHandler(
    (int threshold, string i, string o) => { Console.WriteLine($"threshold={threshold}i={i}, o={o}"); },
    thresholdOpt, infileOpt, outfileOpt);
```

Comment: Thanks! It's surprising to me that this doesn't  seem to work. What I actually need is a number of general options that are always present and then one or more commands, each of which has its own set of distinct options. I'll  investigate using rootCommand.Parse() but I suspect I'll have to do more work myself if I go down that route.

Comment: Something that could be considered is setting some options as global options.

Comment: @AndrewMcClement yes, I mention this in the code in the comments - _"also `rootCommand.AddGlobalOption` can be a more valid approach"_